# position of adverb 'extremely'

Tags: adverb-placement

The following is a sorting question from "*Great Writing 5*"(National Geographic)

to persuade/ it can be/ higher taxes/ to vote for/ difficult/ citizens/ extremely

In the given sentences, the answer sheet says that correct placement of "extremely" is in sentence 1.
I believe that 1 is correct. However, my student questioned if 2 could also be correct.
Is it possible to place the adverb "extremely" before "higher taxes"?
I think it is not good because 'higher taxes' is a kind of　noun phrase and adverb does not emphasize noun phrase. But I'm not sure my position is correct or not. Please let me know whether (2) is OK or not. And if it is true, would it be possible to do the same with adverbs like "significantly" or "substantially"?

> 1. It can be extremely difficult to persuade citizens to vote for
>    higher taxes.
> 2. It can be difficult to persuade citizens to vote for extremely
>    higher taxes

Comment: It depends on which adjective you're trying to modify, "difficult" or "higher".

Comment: @BillJ  Thank you for your comment. The question is from the text book from "Great Writing 5"( National Geographic Learning) and the answer book shows (1) is the correct answer. However, if we want to emphasize 'higher', is it possible to put 'extremely' in front of 'higher taxes'?

Comment: _Extremely higher_ doesn't sound idiomatic (though _extremely high_ would be).

Comment: I don't think it's syntactically valid to modify adverbial ***extremely*** before adverbial ***higher***. If you want to be emphatic, the intensifier needs to modify an *adjective* modifying the relevant noun: *extremely **high** taxes*. But that loses information from the original text, which references ***higher*** taxes than ***current*** taxes.

Comment: For the second one: **much higher taxes** *sounds* better.

Comment: You have a choice. You can either say "extremely **high** taxes" or "much **higher** taxes". You can't really use "extremely" with the comparative "higher" in this context. It's a bit unusual, and not idiomatic, at least in this particular context. There may be some exceptions, but such usage is [extremely rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extremely+higher%2C+much+higher&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). I suspect some may consider it ungrammatical.

Comment: See this related question: [Can we use adverbs with comparative adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542612/can-we-use-adverbs-with-comparative-adjectives#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20can%27t%20modify,comparative%20adjectives%20with%20ly-adverbs.)

Comment: @JapaneseEnglishteacher In the NP "extremely higher taxes", the adverb "extremely" would be modifying "higher", though that NP is not natural; we'd normally say "much higher taxes". The more salient answer is that "extremely" is intended to modify the adjective "difficult".

Comment: Thank you all! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

'Higher' is a *comparative adjective*. It is used to make a direct comparison between *two* objects. It makes sense to talk about proposed 'higher taxes' because they are higher in comparison to the *current* tax rates.

It doesn't make sense to say "extremely higher". 'Extremes' are the highest or lowest *extremities* of any scale. 'Extremely high' taxes would mean that they were among the absolute highest anywhere, so it would, in effect, be being compared to *all* taxes, and the use of a comparative term is not appropriate.